# How to use filter_horizontal on a ForeignKey between two apps using ContentTypes in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Say I have this app named Pantry that is to connect to any other app I may come along. To keep the app decoupled, generic relations are used through the model LinkedItem which connects the Ingredients model to apps outside Pantry.

I would like the content on the other end of the generic relation, say an app named Bakery, to be able to do a filter_horizontal with Ingredients.

**Pantry**
*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import fields

class Ingredient(models.Model):
   '''
   Model containing all the ingredients, their slugs, and their descriptions
   '''
   name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

   # method to return the name of the db entry
   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class LinkedItem(models.Model):
   '''
   Model that links ingredients to various other content models
   '''
   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   content_object = fields.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

   ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)

   # method to return the name of the db entry
   def __str__(self):
      return self.ingredient.name

   # defines options for the model itself
   class Meta:
     unique_together = (('content_type','object_id'))    # prevents duplicates
```

**Bakery**
*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from bakery.models import Cake

class CakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   filter_horizontal = ('') # what to put here so ingredients show up?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what the [`GenericRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation) is for, so you need to add one to your `Cake` model and use it's name in your CakeAdmin.

But you need to use Inlines if you don't want to do a lot of workaround as [M2M fields are not supported for relations with intermediary models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models).

Comment: GenericRelation does not work as filter_horizontal wants a M2M field. What is the workaround you are talking about?

Comment: Well you didn't have a M2M field to begin with. If you really really need the filter_horizontal widget write widget customization and a custom `CakeAdmin.save_model`. Or work with the framework and use [Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).